# Is there a standard scale for building "minifig scale" creations?

Tags: minifigures, scale, moc

I've seen many impressive models built to "minifig scale" (e.g. the enormous **[USS Harry S. Truman](http://www.brothers-brick.com/2006/05/29/malle-hawking-completes-uss-harry-s-truman/)** aircraft carrier), but is there a standard (or at least widely adopted) scale e.g. 1:60 that these models obey?

It seems any scale based on the height of a minifig won't work due to the fact the minifigs are not well proportioned for people. For example, I stand taller than my car (as do most people) yet trying to build a LEGO car that is less than four bricks high would be extremely difficult and result in an unusual looking model.

Are there any tips on choosing a scale that allows well proportioned looking models, that doesn't dwarf the LEGO minifigures that ride in/on them? Is "minifig scale" dependent on the type of model (vehicle/castle) or generally deemed to be whatever looks about right?

Comment: Indeed, most cars are 4 or 6 studs wide, but to get two minifigs next to each other you really need to be at least 8 wide.

Comment: Here's an article on a related topic — Lego train width — which anyone who finds this question interesting will probably enjoy: http://archives.indylug.org/blogs/jeramy_spurgeon/archive/2006/11/02/The-Great-LEGO_AE00_-Train-Width-Debate.aspx

Comment: Here's another train-related note: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_model#cite_note-0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually 1:40, based on the minifig size.

However, keep in mind that a minifig doesn't have the same proportions as a full-size human being, so scaling from real-world to minifig-world is not an exact science. Just have a look at LEGO cars, you'll see that they don't really match real cars.

Answer (score 5):

I think what is interesting is that buildings are usually scaled to things other than minifigures.

For instance, a aircraft carrier would be built to airplane's scale, not the actual minifigures.

Most buildings are scaled to the size of the LEGO doors & windows.

Answer (score 5):

Minifigs don't have the same proportions as average humans. They are comparable to a 600 pound male. Based on minifig height,  the scale is about 1:45. Based on minifig width, the scale is about 1:32. If you're making a building, you probably want to follow a 1:45 scale. If you're making a vehicle, you probably want to go with a 1:32 scale. One rule of thumb I read is that each pip equals about 1 foot.

Answer (score 3):

Minifigures are not to scale. Lego has a greater emphasis on play then realism, so every thing is scaled to suit the minifigures.